# Angular Jasmine Unit test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Basic Folder Structure and my app.spec.js file
[image]

My internal folder Structure :

[image: this is my folder structure]

kamra config file :
I have given the proper path for angularjs file in karma.config.js, but still it is showing angularjs is not defined.
What can be the possible problem here and solution.

[image: this is my config file]

Error ,I'm getting:

[image: this error I'm getting]

All answers welcome :)

Comment: remove the ./ and try it

Comment: @rrd : I tried that too, but still getting same error :(

Comment: Try using an absolute path.

Comment: can u check with ../

Comment: yes, I check this also, but nothing seems to work @SaEChowdary

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you all** for your response.

This Problem has been solved.
Main reason was, I was referring different version of file for angularjs in my `index.html` page and `karma.config.js` file.
I tried with same version of file and It solved the problem.

If you are getting `angular is not defined error`,give reference to same version of file. e.g. like you have given V 1.5.5 for angularjs, give same version of file reference in karma.config.js.